# How can I change the state of my sidebar in my React with Redux ASP.NET Core application?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, redux

I'm new to both React and Redux and I'm working on building my first web application.  The application I'm building has a sidebar which I've created using [Material UI Drawer](https://material-ui.com/demos/drawers/).  It's triggered with a button contained within the sidebar component but I don't want that, what I want to do is have the button sitting within a different component and the state of the `drawer` be handled by `Redux`.

As I'm new to this I was hoping someone could help me out.  Here is my code.

> I have not wired up my store to my component as I'm not clear on the
>   best way to do this given my requirement

**src/components/Sidebar.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Drawer from '@material-ui/core/Drawer';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import Divider from '@material-ui/core/Divider';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import ListItemIcon from '@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
import InboxIcon from '@material-ui/icons/MoveToInbox';
import MailIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Mail';

const styles = {
    list: {
        width: 250,
    },
    fullList: {
        width: 'auto'
    },
};

class Sidebar extends React.Component {
    state = {        
        show: false,        
    };

    toggleDrawer = (side, open) => () => {
        this.setState({
            [side]: open,
        });
    };

    render() {
        const { classes } = this.props;

        const sideList = (
            <div className={classes.list}>
                <List>
                    <ListItem button component={Link} to="/">
                        <ListItemIcon>
                            <InboxIcon />
                        </ListItemIcon>
                        <ListItemText primary="Home" />
                    </ListItem>                    
                </List>
                <Divider />
                <List>
                    {['All mail', 'Trash', 'Spam'].map((text, index) => (
                        <ListItem button key={text}>
                            <ListItemIcon>{index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}</ListItemIcon>
                            <ListItemText primary={text} />
                        </ListItem>
                    ))}
                </List>
            </div>
        );
        return (
            <div>
                <Drawer open={this.state.show} onClose={this.toggleDrawer('show', false)}>
                    <div
                        tabIndex={0}
                        role="button"
                        onClick={this.toggleDrawer('show', false)}
                        onKeyDown={this.toggleDrawer('show', false)}
                    >
                        {sideList}
                    </div>
                </Drawer>                
            </div>
        );
    }
}

Sidebar.propTypes = {
    classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(Sidebar);
```

As you can see the `drawer` has a `state` called `show` which is set to `false` initially.  In the above code the `state` is stored locally but I'm not sure that is correct for using Redux.

Here is my `layout` where I'd like the button to live, it may not be here all the time but for the sake of this question let's say it live here.

**src/components/Layout.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Container } from 'reactstrap';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Sidebar from './Sidebar';

export default props => (
    <div className="beta">
        <Sidebar />
      <Button onClick={this.toggleDrawer('show', true)}>Open</Button>
        <div className="container-fluid">
            {props.children}
        </div>
    </div>
);
Container.propTypes = {
    fluid: PropTypes.bool
}
```

I realize that this button won't work in the above code because it can't access the state in toggleDrawer.

**src/store/configureStore.js**

```
import { applyMiddleware, combineReducers, compose, createStore } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { routerReducer, routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux';
import * as Stage from './Stage';

export default function configureStore(history, initialState) {
    const reducers = {
        sidebar: Stage.reducer
  };

  const middleware = [
    thunk,
    routerMiddleware(history)
  ];

  // In development, use the browser's Redux dev tools extension if installed
  const enhancers = [];
  const isDevelopment = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';
  if (isDevelopment && typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.devToolsExtension) {
    enhancers.push(window.devToolsExtension());
  }

  const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    ...reducers,
    routing: routerReducer
  });

  return createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    compose(applyMiddleware(...middleware), ...enhancers)
  );
}
```

**src/store/Stage.js**

```
const sidebarOpen = 'SIDEBAR_OPEN';
const initialState = { show: false }

export const actionCreators = {
    open: () => ({
        type: sidebarOpen
    })    
};

export const reducer = (state, action) => {
    state = state || initialState;
    console.log("Initial State");
    console.log(state)
    if (action.type === sidebarOpen) {
        return {
            ...state,
            show: state.show = true
        };
    } else {
        return {            
            ...state,
            show: state.show = false
        }
    }    
    return state;
};
```

The above is my rather crude attempt to write an action and a reducer that would be capable of passing true or false to the sidebar and open it up.  I need help, how can I (simply) tell redux to alter the state of my sidebar when the menu button is clicked which is in my layout?

Any help and guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would suggest you to replace your

```
if (action.type === sidebarOpen) {
       someaction..
    } else {
       someaction..
    }
```

with

```
switch(action.type) 
{
   case XXX: someaction; break;
    case YYY: someaction; break;
    default: somedefaultaction; break;
}
```

in *src/store/Stage.js* it will be more readable when the reducer will grow enough.

Now, about your concern, the step that is missing in your current implementaton is the mapping of state/props with the reducer.

Have a look at the following code :

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    myVar: state.myVarFromReducer,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    expandFn: () => expand(dispatch),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(myComponent);
```

Let's ignore the `mapDispatchToProps`, it will not be used for our concern.

*I invite you to see https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate and https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch for a better understanding of connection between redux & react.*

NB : this code sample often appears at the end of the component's file.

What we have here is a bind `connect(mapStateToProps,..)(myComponent)` of the specified state with my component. 
The specified state are the values you have defined in *src/store/Stage.js* for example.

So, in your situation, you have to `connect` your component with the store, exactly how its done above.
Then you have to map the information of the reducer state you want to have in your component state. 
It will look like this :

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    show: state.show,
});
```

Basically, this means "bind the attribute `show` of my component's state with the reducer's attribute `show`".

If the `show` attribute of the reducer change, the component will be notified and his `show` attribute will be updated.